# How is the Baire theorem being used in the proof of the open mapping theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I am following the famous *Complex and Real analysis* by Walter Rudin and I am looking at the Proof of the Open Mapping Theorem (5.9):

> Let $U$ and $V$ be open unit balls of the Banach spaces $X$ and $Y$.
>   To every bounded linear transformation $\Lambda $ of $X$ onto $Y$
>   there corresponds a $\delta > 0$ s.t. $\Lambda(U) \supset \delta V$

I don't understand how during the proof, after having observed that $Y$ is the union of the sets $\Lambda(k U)$ for $k = 1,2,3, \dots$ it is claimed that since $Y$ is complete Baire's Theorem implies that there exists a nonempty set $W$ in the closure of some $\Lambda(kU)$.

Baire's theorem is a statement on the intersection of a dense collecttion of open set, how is it being used here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An equivalent formulation of Baire's Lemma is the following:

> Let $(X,d)$ be a complete metric space. If $X = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty F_n$, with $F_n$ closed for every $n$, then there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $F_N$ has nonempty interior.

Indeed, if you assume by contradiction that the interior of $F_n$ is empty for every $n$, then the sets $V_n := X\setminus F_n$ are open and dense in $X$, so that, by Baire's Lemma, there exists $x \in \bigcap_n V_n$, in contradiction with
$$
\bigcap_n V_n = \bigcap_n F_n^C = \left(\bigcup_n F_n\right)^C = X^C = \emptyset.
$$